# Где быстрое выполнится пустой цикл?

Tags: linux, c, kernel

один и тот же цикл написанный как модуль ядра и как обычное приложение в user mode, быстродействие будет одинаковым или нет?

Comment: Пустой цикл будет выброшен хорошим оптимизатором при компиляции. Так что в обоих случаях вы получите ноль.

Comment: @VladD А что быстрее будет работать, если сравнивать netfilter hook, который подменяет адрес назначения и какой-нибудь прокси-сервер? Спасибо.

Comment: Хм, это как-то совсем как-то отходит от первоначальной темы вопроса. Я не думаю, что можно просто так рассуждать о скорости _произвольного_ прокси-сервера, зависит от подробностей имплементации.

Comment: @Vladimir откорректируйте свой вопрос, чтобы он не звучал так бредово.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Зачем вы спрашиваете про некий цикл если вас интересует нечто иное. Процессор с одинаковой скоростью выполнит одинаковый код как в ядре так и в user space. При условии, что данный код и все данные присутствуют в оперативной памяти.

Дальнейший ответ основан на ваших комментариях к вопросу...

Вопрос лишь в том, что за код надо выполнять и надо ли при этом переключать контекст. Что бы пакет попал в user space в прокси сервер и был послан ответ должно произойти следующее:

1. Ядро получает аппаратное прерывание от сетевой карты. Драйвер и другие функции сетевого стека формируют структуру skbuf.
2. IP Стек понимает, что пакет должен попасть приложению на данной машине в user space. Весь объем пакета копируется из памяти PL0 (ядра) в память PL3 (процесса).
3. Происходит переключение контекста на PL3 (user space). Операция сама по себе довольно накладная.
4. Код прокси разбирает пакет, решает что запрос надо послать дальше, формирует посылаемый пакет у себя в памяти, вызывает функцию send ядра.
5. Происходит переключение контекста на PL0 (ядро)
6. Ядро копирует весь пакет из памяти PL3 в PL0.
7. Ядро дописывает заголовки TCP/IP/физического уровней и отдает драйверу на отправку.

При работе кода пересылающего пакет целиком в ядре пункты с 2 по 6 не нужны, в том числе двойное копирование пакета в памяти и два переключения контекста. За счет этого операции исключительно в ядре значительно быстрее. Но приложение user space может пойти не стандартным путем, а обрабатывать пакеты например средствами netmap, которые позволяют как минимум избежать операций копирования за счет отображения структур ядра непосредственно в виртуальную память процесса PL3.

P.S. Уровни защиты памяти приведены для архитектуры intel x86. Для других архитектур они отличаются с сохранением общего смысла необходимой работы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваши ответы, очень помогли в освоении программирования модуля ядра Linux. Почему в комментарии другой вопрос, не хотел плодить похожую тему.